# How do I echo a specific part of this session array?

Tags: php, arrays, session, echo

When trying to print/echo a specific part of my session array it wont return anything besides a '1'

it also gives an error telling me that `user_name` is an undefined index but when I `var_dump` my session it shows it exists.

What is the correct way to only show the `user_name` part of my session on screen?

I've tried `print_r`, `echo`, `print` but none of these seem to work

```
session_start();

include '../php/database.php';
var_dump($_SESSION['userdata']);
echo "Welcome back " . print_r($_SESSION['userdata']['user_name'][0]) . "!";
```

I expect the output to be "Welcome back user_name" which in this case should be the text string "empty"

var_dump:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(8) { ["user_id"]=> string(1) "1" [0]=> string(1) "1" ["user_name"]=> string(5) "empty" [1]=> string(5) "empty" ["user_pass"]=> string(5) "empty" [2]=> string(5) "empty" ["user_email"]=> string(17) "empty@hotmail.com" [3]=> string(17) "empty@hotmail.com" } } }
```

output

> Notice: Undefined index: user_name in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Projecten\loginSystem\pages\dashboard.php on line 7
>   Welcome back 1!

Comment: Have you checked whether your structure really matches? As far as I see, there is no element `user_name` within the given dump - the array has a single element, another array, at index `0`

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned your session data is like:

```
array(1) {
    [0]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> array(8) { 
            ["user_id"]=> string(1) "1" [0]=> string(1) "1" 
            ["user_name"]=> string(5) "empty" [1]=> string(5) "empty" 
            ["user_pass"]=> string(5) "empty" [2]=> string(5) "empty" 
            ["user_email"]=> string(17) "empty@hotmail.com" [3]=> string(17) "empty@hotmail.com" 
        } 
    } 
}
```

To get **user_name**, You will have to travel through your array as:

```
echo $_SESSION['userdata'][0][0]['user_name'];
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 arrays in your session
Do it this way:

```
echo "Welcome back " . print_r($_SESSION['userdata'][0][0]['user_name']) . "!";
```